How to apply "where" in select from DataGridView using C#
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio and I have the "Box Number" column in a DataGridView as follows:



Box Number




4433002


4433006


4433011



I want to execute SQL query like:
"SELECT NOTE FROM TABLE WHERE BOX_NUMBER IN (DataGridView_List)"
I have tried this:
"SELECT NOTE FROM TABLE WHERE BOX_NUMBER IN '" + dataGridView4.SelectAll() + "'";
But it still has an error.

Where do you need the results to appear? More information of what you're trying to do is needed to be able to assist here.
If you just want to be able to retrieve the data for later on, try creating a DataTable which is populated with the Box_Number values, and use that DataTable to populate your grid for the visual results. You can then use that DataTable elsewhere and apply a query/filter to that rather than using the gridview.
